# Can you use the command `\polyhornerscheme` with letters in the coefficients place?

Tags: polynom

I'd like to know if it's possible to use letters instead of numbers using the `polynom` package and the `\polyhornerscheme` command?

Something like:

```
\polyhornerscheme[x=2,stage=5,tutorlimit=2,tutor=true,resultleftrule=true,resultbottomrule=true]{k*x^3+x^2-1}
```

Comment: What happens when you do that? The answer to your question is either **Yes** or **No**, depending on the outcome.

Comment: when I compile it shows some result but the calculations are wrong.

Comment: So the answer is No. Calculations are performed on the coefficients and `k` is not a number.